# Why .getIdentifier() retreive a number from class?

Tags: android, string, class, identifier

When I try to get a string from an activity, "getIdentifier" works fine:

Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getIdentifier("frase", "string", getPackageName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

But when try it from non activity class, it retreive a number (e.g.: 2131099793):

getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("frase" , "string", getContext().getPackageName();

Why does this happen?

Comment: If you want to get a string, use getString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIdentifier()` returns an `int`, as you can see in [the JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). That `int` is the identifier of the resource. In your case, it is the same `int` that `R.string.frase` is.

In your first code snippet, you pass that resource identifier to `Toast.makeText()`. `makeText()` assumes that if you pass it an `int`, that the `int` is a string resource identifier, so it looks up the string resource and uses it.

In your second code snippet, you are just using the `int`. Use `getString()` to convert an `int` resource identifier into the corresponding string for your current configuration.